# Docker Failed to Initialize on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have problem regarding pulling docker-dev in a docker image for making my development environment. When I tried to pull docker-dev, I got an error like "docker manifest not found."

Can anyone help me out with this error?

I want to know about the docker failed to initialize error which I'm getting right now.

The error is like this:
[image]

I tried so many things like re-installing the docker desktop or WSL updates, but none of those worked.

The error in the command is like this:
[image]

Comment: Run Powershell as administrator and do not forget to do `docker login` first

Comment: **Its showing same error as for the connection**
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker login 
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one. 
Username: *********
Password:    
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/auth": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. @Facty

Comment: Hi did you resolve this. I am also getting same error. Stragely enough you have posted the question 6 days ago, very recently

Comment: @anandhu yah i've resolve this few month ago....you can go through the answer which is marked below.....thank you.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Got the same issue and fixed it by deleting `%appdata%\Docker` as mentioned by Github User "tocklime"

(Original Source : https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3088)
[image]

Comment: I have reinstalled the Docker app, but this is indeed the solution that worked for this new version, thanks

Comment: this solution is working on 2021, plus i have uninstalled all my hyper-v softwares like virtual box, it might be causing conflicts within docker deskptop

Comment: I had previously installed and uninstalled the docker, probably that's causing the issue, but your solution works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for such a useful comment. And thank you @tocklime for your beautiful answer.

Comment: I've got 3 folders within %AppData% - Local, LocalLow, and Roaming. In Local there are folders called "Docker" and "Docker Desktop Installer" and in Roaming there are folders called "Docker" and "Docker Desktop". Which of these do I delete? (FWIW I just uninstalled Docker and all these folders are still there).

Comment: same issue as @some_randomer on Windows 10 - I just deleted all of them and it started working (although I did have to reinstall and lost all my containers and images, altho that was cool coz that was what I was trying to do) - thanks all

Comment: Perfect. this really solved the issue. thank you so much. I was really worried if i had to unisntall docker which is the worst case in my work right now.

Comment: Solution by nessunluogo is better since it fixes the problem without wiping your containers.

Answer (score 39):

Short solution: delete `%appdata%\Docker\settings.json` and let Docker to create a new one.

Take a backup of the file for the next time it gets broken.

---

### <tl;dr>

I face this issue almost every month and I hope this will get fixed definitely.

Following *tmBlackCape* answer, I checked the %appdata%\Docker directory and found settings.json damaged (editor tells it's a binary file and of course it shouldn't).

I deleted the file and Docker Service (still running) created a new one with default values. If the service isn't running, just launch it again.

You could need to change settings (via GUI, as recommended) to catch your needs.

I made a backup copy of my custom settings.json so next time I can replace the broken one without losing custom configuration.

Comment: deleting the `%AppData%\Docker` folder worked for me

Comment: Deleting `settings.json` in `%appdata%\Docker` is worked for me. No need to delete entire Docker directory. Just `settings.json` is enough. Then, open Docker. It should works!

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution, IMO, since it means you don't lose your containers etc.

Answer (score 22):

Go to the directory  ***C:\Users-------\AppData\Roaming\Docker*** and delete the file ***settings.json*** . Docker takes care of rewriting it at startup.

This manipulation solved the problem for me !

Answer (score 13):

The error message I got was not exactly the same the OP got. For me, it said `Docker failed to initialize. Docker Desktop is shutting down`.

**TL;DR**

The `powershell` executable was missing from my local machies `PATH`. I had to add `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` and docker started again.

**The longer story**

I tried everything that was mentined in this thread and nothing worked for me. When I looked at the task manager of my local machine to see if any docker-related process was started, I noticed that `Docker Desktop.exe` itself was started. However, the `com.docker.backend.exe` not. Docker tries to start that exe in an infinite loop, but as soon as it started it crashed again after half a second.

I then took a look into `com.docker.backend.exe.log`, which is located in `%localappdata%\Docker\log\host` and noticed the following line:

```
[2022-07-07T10:46:57.936079700Z][com.docker.backend.exe][F] exec: "powershell": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

I then went ahead and just added the path to `powershell` to `PATH` (which is `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`)`. As soon as I added that, everything started working again.

I have no idea how the path to the powershell executable got removed from `PATH`. I certainly did not do that myself.

Comment: We encountered the same issue. Thanks all of your valuable comments.

Comment: Wow, i have been searching for hours. +1

Comment: very informative to know where to search the next error for.  In my case I had to upgrade the powershell too

Comment: Heyhey! Might be a bit later; but this could explain your path issues. Windows path has a length limit (I think like 1000), and certain commands will literally overwrite parts of your path to make room. This can be circumvented using other commands.

Comment: This worked for me on windows, thanks saved the day

Answer (score 11):

*Docker failed to initialize*

***C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Docker***

***C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Docker***

***C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop***

Once deleted above directory, I didn’t have to do anything else, Docker Desktop started booting up as normal.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after Docker Desktop upgrade to version 3.6.0 (67351), too.  (Which was surprising, because it worked before the upgrade.)

Due to the help in the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194286/416688) right now, I went to the above settings directory: `%appdata%\Docker`, looked at the logs and **deleted/renamed the file settings.json** -> **Docker Desktop started immediatelly** ; there had been a process retrying in the background.

In the time before that, the backend.exe.log had been all *"unmarshal"* something something:

```
    settings.json: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field Content.proxyHttpMode of type string"
common/cmd/com.docker.backend/internal/settingsloader.GetSettings(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

So, the above message 'tipped me off' as to where the actual error on start may be.  Hmm...

Comment: I realized after posting this, that another answer also found to rename/delete the file.. 

Answer (score 3):

For me deleting the folder %appdata%\Docker did not work.

Instead I had to run the following power shell command as admin.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

References.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63845592/1977871
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-hyper-v-using-powershell

My windows features with running docker desktop are as follows.

[image: Screen shot of windows features]

Comment: On my side, on the opposite, uninstalling HyperV did the trick :
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor

Answer (score 3):

For me the solutions here didn't help, but here's what helped.

1. Make sure the folder `.docker/` in your home directory isn't marked as hidden in Windows. If it's hidden, Docker won't see it.
2. Make sure docker has Active Directory to `.docker` folder. For example, if the owner of `.docker/` is `SYSTEM` and not your user, Docker won't be able to read it and crash.

Comment: Thank you! First solution has worked for me on Windows 10 Home!

Answer (score 3):

It resolved me by deleting the file
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution worked for me! No need to edit the registry and perform 10+ other steps as other solutions suggest

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I'm on Docker Desktop 4.8.0. The following solution worked for me:

1. Uninstall Docker Desktop
2. Delete .docker folder from `C:\Users\{Username}`
3. Delete Docker folder from `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local`
4. Delete Docker folder from `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming`
5. Delete Docker folder from `C:\Program Files`
6. Run CCleaner on Registry and Custom Clean
7. Restart Computer
8. Install Docker
9. Restart Computer
10. Start Docker

That's all.

Comment: Thanks man!! None of the other solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local and delete Downloaded Installation directory.
2. C:\Users\asd\AppData\Roaming and delete  Docker and Docker Desktop directory.

Then start docker.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't found the AppData folder in users[myUser] or anywhere. re-install solve it for me

Answer (score 1):

latest update 4.10.1 has issues, i downgraded to 4.6.1 and it worked however i think powershell is closely linked to this issue

Answer (score 0):

It happened due to local data corruption. You can check in VM log inside `%appdata%\Docker.`
I was able to reset and restart by renaming `setting.json` and then restart the Docker desktop by deleting all the previous log folder and temp folder clean. If this does not help.
Try to kill all the processes running in through the task manager
[image]

and then run `Power shell` in administrator mode and then shoot the command if you are using an older version of Lsmanager  `Restart-Service LxssManager`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my side, uninstalling HyperV did the trick :

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
```

I also (as suggested in the voted answer):

- Uninstalled docker desktop,
- Deleted any docker related content in %APPDATA% as suggested
- Delete any docker related keyys in registry (may be not necessary)
- Then reinstalled it

And it solved the problem (but without hyperV removal it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few great solutions; however, it didn't work for me. Most of the "fixes" suggested here are already implemented and it just didn't work. I chose a different approach.
I looked at the docker releases and saw what was actually affected by their latest version not working (4.10). These things are normal, especially if the software engine has been updated.
Going through Docker releases, the latest release that didn't touch the Docker engine is 4.8.0. I downloaded and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `settings.json` file or `%AppData%\Docker` folder did not work for me. After uninstalling/installing the docker, the issue was solved. (Note: I couldn't try other possible solutions that are required the admin privilege)

Answer (score 0):

The below Steps worked for me,

**Step 01:**
Navigate to the below-mentioned paths and delete the below-mentioned directories,

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Docker directory

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Docker directory

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop  directory

Then restart the docker again

**If you didn't find the AppData folder in users[USERNAME] or anywhere**

**Step 02:**  Type the below path in the "Run" to directly open the app data location for you

```
%appdata%\Docker
```

Then Delete the below-mentioned directories,

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Docker  directory

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Docker  directory

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop  directory

Then restart the docker again

Note: If these steps do not help you. Try to kill all the processes running in through the task manager. And again delete the directories and start the docker

Answer (score 0):

if you still can't find the issue you may use this trick and i'm 100% sure this will work

first check your operating system is up to date means no remaining updates if you pass this step then come to 2 step open window command prompt in run as administrator
then type wsl --install then type wsl --list --online then wsl --install -d Debian
then open docker if error come
then install wsl 2 linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

then restart docker or your machine and then if error also occur then type then wsl --update   i hope this will work Regard : Hammad Khadim

Answer (score 0):

In my case, given the same error what happened is that I was running in the background the 'docker desktop' and since it did not let me run it again, although it did not tell me that it was already running.
From the 'Process Explorer' I killed it.

As a comment what in my case I detected that presented the error is that I made a download of the image "registry.hf.space/bhaskartripathi-pdfchatter:latest" and while this happened the wsl / 'docker desktop' gave error and closed.

---

An observation, when I wanted to run an image that had assigned volumes, it gave an error. What I did was to rename the "C:{USER}{USER}{AppData\Roaming\Docker}settings.json" to initialize the 'docker desktop', in this way I could remove the volumes and then run the image without problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what worked for me. I have Docker Desktop 4.24.2 installed. Resetting the Docker Desktop to factory defaults fixed my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gonna throw in a scenario that I observed:

My error message was this:

```
Docker failed to initialize

Docker Desktop is shutting down.
```

Fixes, such as deleting Docker specific `AppData` did not resolve the problem. What did solve the issue is a simple reboot of Windows.

Here is what likely happened: The machine was supposed to be restarted after doing updates, however some process prevented the shutdown. While Windows remained running and simply showed the login screen, some Windows services were no longer running. Likely one of them is a Docker dependency. Because the screen looked the same as it would after a reboot, the lack of reboot went unnoticed. Because the machine presumably was just rebooted, rebooting to try if the Docker issue is resolved, did not immediately cross my mind. I then noticed that some applications that would usually auto-start were not running without me having shut them down, so then I realized what had happened. After the reboot the daemon started up normally.

TL;DR: Before you try more complex fixes - try rebooting first. Make sure the machine actually reboots, as in, observe it rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after deleting both %appdata%\Docker and %appdata%\Docker Desktop directories for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have just ended the process "Docker Desktop.exe" in the task manager. Started the Docker Desktop, it worked.